# PHP and form data validation

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am a beginner in PHP-Codeignitor.So i dont know this question too waste for you guys.

But is there any easy way to validate form data ?

Ex.I have a table and it contain a text field "username",there is a insert button too,whern user clicked on insert it will add another text field.

So how can i get the value(s) in php ? because user can add any number of fields there.

$username = $_POST("username"); //what it will retrieve in this case ? array ?

Also how can handle situation like this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set an array in the form, you will get an array in $_POST.

form fields:

```
<input type='text' name='username[]' />
<input type='text' name='username[]' />
```

php:

```
$users_array = $_POST['username'];
```

Comment: @DileepDil I'm a little disappointed you didn't mark this as the correct answer though.

Comment: Pardon me , other answers also correct with some example code.This is one of the worst feature of SO ,

Answer (score 1):

If your users are going to add a number of fields, you should let them do it with [HTML array input](http://www.johnrockefeller.net/html-input-forms-sending-in-an-array-in-php/). Something like:

```
<input name="my_array[]" />
```

Here is [form_validation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) usage with HTML array input:

1. Get the input array to determine how many fields are there
2. Set rules for each field

Simple enough? :) Here is my demo code:

Controller: `application/controllers/test.php`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
* Test Controller
*
* It's really just a test controller
*
*/
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = array();
        if ($this->input->post('test_submit'))
        {
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $input_array = $this->input->post('test');

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($input_array); $i++)
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules("test[$i]", 'Test Field '.($i + 1), 'trim|is_numeric|xss_clean');
            }

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
            {
                $data['message'] = 'All input are number! Great!';
            }
        }
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view('test', $data);
    }

}

/* End of file test.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/test.php */
```

View: `application/views/test.php`

```
<p><?php echo isset($message) ? $message : ''; ?></p>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
    <?php echo form_label('Test fields (numeric)', 'test[]'); ?>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++): ?>
        <?php echo form_input('test[]', set_value("test[$i]")); ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php echo form_submit('test_submit', 'Submit'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

URL: `<your_base_url_here>/index.php/test`
Check it out :D

***NOTE***: `numeric` and `is_numeric` rules both require input, which mean empty strings are not numeric.